# How to set error correction level for QR code when using the new createbitmap method

Tags: blackberry, qr-code, zxing

This question is in reference to the API documentation link, http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/barcodelib/BarcodeBitmap.html

They specify that the old method

```
public static Bitmap createBitmap(ByteMatrix byteMatrix,
                                  int maxBitmapSizeInPixels)
```

is deprecated.

But by using the new method,

```
public static Bitmap createBitmap(ByteMatrix byteMatrix)
```

they haven't specified a way to specify the error correction level for the QR code in Multiformatwriter. I haven't been able to find a way either, looking through various member functions. 
Has anyone tried this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looked to the documentation.

It says to use `createBitmap(ByteMatrix byteMatrix)` in conjunction with `MultiFormatWriter`. That has method `encode(String contents, BarcodeFormat format, int width, int height, Hashtable hints)` where you could specify width, height and error level.

To specify error level put to hints hashtable key `EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION` with value `new Integer(level)`.

Unfortunately I didn't find any constants for these values as described [here](http://tech.top21.de/techblog/20100706-generating-qr-codes-in-java-with-zxing.html;jsessionid=125F3520AE46F953065CC3EE7D6A316F). but probably you could find it in axing sources.

Comment: If you are referring to these two lines in the doc, I too looked at them. `MultiFormatWriter barcodeWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();
ByteMatrix barcode = barcodeWriter.encode("abcdefg", BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 25, 25);` But they don't provide a way to mention the Error correction level for the QR code.

Comment: check my answer below for specifics on how to pass in settings for Error correction hints, using ZXing's built-in constants

Answer (score 6):

Here is my code, and I have checked with my phone, the error correction level is set correctly according to my phone.

```
        Hashtable hints = new Hashtable();
        switch (comboBox1.Text)
        {
            case "L":
                hints.Add(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.L);
                break;
            case "Q":
                hints.Add(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.Q);
                break;
            case "H":
                hints.Add(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.H);
                break;
            default: 
                hints.Add(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.M);
                break;
        }
        MultiFormatWriter mw = new MultiFormatWriter();
        ByteMatrix bm = mw.encode(data, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, size, size, hints);
        Bitmap img = bm.ToBitmap();
        pictureBox1.Image = img;
```

Comment: What OS do you have in your phone?

Answer (score 2):

When encoding, you can pass in hints

```
Map<EncodeHintType, Object> hints = new Hastable<EncodeHintType, Object>();
```

Add the error correction setting to the hints (for example to level M)

```
hints.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.M);
```

ZXing uses error correction level L by default (the lowest, meaning the QR Code will still be readable even after a max of 7% damage)