# Different pattern between qrcode image

Tags: java, qr-code, zxing

I need to implement an old system that doesn't have source code.
The system prints labels with the following qrcode output: (QR version 6 41x41, **alignment patterns** only 1)

[image: Version 1]

I tried to make the program in Java using the Zxing library.
However, the resulting output has different as with previous below: (QR version >= 7,**alignment patterns** = 6)

[image: Version 2]

Even if both reading scanners will produce the same output and character length (154@char)

```
"H 4A91K       BB7998  M11AU10406   CBU 4A91471     H 000160        69H 69578 00009Y000                            @N                                      "
```

Maybe, it seems related to the qr lower version.
I tried to make a lower qr.version but got the following error:

```
com.google.zxing.WriterException: Data too big for requested version
    at com.google.zxing.qrcode.encoder.Encoder.encode(Encoder.java:123)
    at com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeWriter.encode(QRCodeWriter.java:78)
```

Can anyone help me how to make qrcode output same as version 1 (**alignment patterns** only 1) ?

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1):

If I checked your expected QR Code have size 41x41 modules which is using version 6.
The version 6 have only one alignment pattern. Your data contains of 1244 bits and the version 6 only have maximum size 1,088 bits for mixed data bits with lower (L) error correction. So, the exception raised because your data is bigger than maximum capacity of QR Code in Version 6 below.
The most possible version for your data is version 7 that have 1,248 bits capacity with lower error correction. But this version have more than one alignment pattern.
I suggest you to try to compress your data to lower your size of data.
[Version 6 Size Description source: https://www.qrcode.com/en/about/version.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVrGQ.png)

Comment: Thank you sir, this is what I mean, I have done several ways but haven't found a way to do the compression in question, can you give an example maybe?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

QR Codes have some redundancy built in to correct for damaged QR codes. When creating a QR code, you may choose the level of error correction. The higher the level, the more information must be included in the QR code for redundancy and thus the larger the QR code must be. It appears that the level of error correction in your reference is lower than in the QR code you created. You may want to have a look at [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11968724/5736633) to see how this can be specified in Z-Xing.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.  But unfortunately, I have tried all the level corrections and other hint parameters.  The result is still the same, I can't generate qr version 1. There is an online generator with the same result but after trying the same properties I still get NG result. https://www.morovia.com/free-online-barcode-generator/qrcode-maker.php